# How to customize folder_contents on Plone 5?

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm on Plone 5 and I want to modify the number of columns that are shown by default on `/folder_contents`.

If I recall correctly, the whole *table* is a pattern that gets initialized with quite a huge JSON data-xxx parameter on the corresponding tag.

So, should I dig into the JSON or rather put my attention on the JS pattern?

Is there any documentation on how to customize it anywhere? A quick google search didn't show up anything relevant to me :-/

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433390/how-to-customize-plone-5s-folder-contents