# How to customize Plone-5's folder_contents

Tags: plone, backend, mockups, plone-5.x

I want to customize Plone's folder_contents to add an 'edit'-link to each listed item, like show in the image below.

How would one do that?

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish.  This is likely already in Plone out of the box (in 5.0.6) for you, in the drop-down for each item in the "Actions" column of the contents.  See: https://snag.gy/rVStpR.jpg

Comment: Yes I know "edit" in the actions column, but our customer wants to change location to operate faster.

Comment: I'm still unclear what you want, but using jbot is the preferred way to make a tiny change to a stock template in an override in (any) add-on package. Google for plone+jbot, and you will find docs.

Comment: Looks to me Andy wants to customize the folder_contents-template and extend each item's row with an edit-link, so one does not have to make the extra click to the single-view first, before being able to  hit edit. With Plone-4 that's easy, but I don't know how it's done with Plone-5.

Comment: @IdaEbkes, Yes, This is what I need. I don't know how it's done with Plone-5, too.

Comment: Have a look at how Castle CMS (a Plone distribution) does it, http://github.com/castlecms/castle.cms

Comment: Also, you may have more luck asking questions in https://community.plone.org

Comment: Plone-5.1 added an edit- and a view-button next to each list-item.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388818/how-to-customize-folder-contents-on-plone-5

Answer (score 0):

There is a file called `table.xml` but I have not tried it. It is very cumbersome to change something internal in Plone.

Comment: Can very much understand your frustration, but please do not use answers for leaving comments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the right way to do it is loading the module and changing it's prototype:

```
var structure = require('mockup-patterns-structure');
structure.prototype.defaults._default_activeColumns = ["ModificationDate","EffectiveDate","review_state","id","Type"]
```